# Spring JDBC の batchUpdate の戻り値の順序について教えてください

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

Spring JDBC の batchUpdate についてです。

```
public int[] org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(java.lang.String sql,
                     java.util.List<java.lang.Object[]> batchArgs)
              throws DataAccessException
```

こちらのメソッドを利用するとUpdate件数を格納したint型の配列が返りますが、この配列の順序は引数 `batchArgs` の順序と一致しているのでしょうか？

例としては、
- batchArgs.get(0)のupdate件数が、戻り値[0]に格納
- batchArgs.get(1)のupdate件数が、戻り値[1]に格納
- batchArgs.get(2)のupdate件数が、戻り値[2]に格納
といったようになっているかどうかです。

javadocを確認しましたが明記はされていないように見受けられましたので、ご存じある方がいらっさいましたらご教授いただきたく思います。
また明記されているサイトをご存じある方がいらっしゃいましたら教えていただきたく思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> この配列の順序は引数 batchArgs の順序と一致しているのでしょうか？

一致すると思います。

[batchUpdate](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#batchUpdate-java.lang.String-java.util.List-)の`Returns:`には、以下の記載があり、`each update in the batch`が`batchArgs`にあたるのだと思います。

> an array containing the numbers of rows affected by each update in the batch

ただ、英語が苦手なので、ソースも確認してみましたが、 batchArgs の順序と一致していました。

---

以下は細かいですが、ソースの解析結果です。

[batchUpdate(String sql, List batchArgs)](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.0.7.RELEASE/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.java#L968)は、

- [BatchUpdateUtils.executeBatchUpdate](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.0.7.RELEASE/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core/BatchUpdateUtils.java#L34)を呼びだし、
- 最後に[batchUpdate(String sql, final BatchPreparedStatementSetter

  pss)](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.0.7.RELEASE/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.java#L919)を呼びだします

そして、[batchUpdate(String sql, final BatchPreparedStatementSetter pss)](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.0.7.RELEASE/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.java#L919)は、

- [JDBC driverがJDBC 2.0 batch updatesをサポートしている場合](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.0.7.RELEASE/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.java#L930)は、[Statement.executeBatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch())を実行し、その結果が`batchUpdate`の戻り値となります。
  [Statement.executeBatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch())の戻り値はJavaDocに配列の順序を明記されているため、**batchArgs の順序と一致**します。
  `an array of update counts containing one element for each command in the batch. The elements of the array are ordered according to the order in which commands were added to the batch.`
- [JDBC driverがJDBC 2.0 batch updatesをサポートしていない場合](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.0.7.RELEASE/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.java#L940)は、`batchArgs`の順にSQLを実行しその結果を戻り値に格納しています。そのため、**batchArgs の順序と一致**します。

Answer (score 0):

Spring JDBCにバグが無ければ、一致しているはずです（が、何か想定外の結果が返ってきましたか？）。

Comment: batchUpdate の処理の中を理解できておらず申し訳ないのですが、もし並列に実行しているような場合には、完了したものから格納されてしまい不一致となるようなケースが起こりえるのではないか、と想定していました。実際に試したところでは一致していたのですが、どこかに明記されていれば安心できると思い、質問させていただきました。